# Were the Constructicons Decepticons before betraying Omega Supreme?

Tags: transformers

In *Transformers G1* episode 47, it isn't clear if the Constructicons were or were not Decepticons before betraying Omega Supreme. The episode seems to have several continuity mistakes, (such as the Constructicons having an Earth-like vehicle form before arriving to Earth), although may be there is an explanation; that's why I'm asking.

The episode says the Constructicons and Omega Supreme were friends. But then Megatron created a robot or machine, which reprogrammed robots he captured through it to serve him. The Constructicons are captured by this robot, reprogrammed to serve Megatron, and betray Omega Supreme. The odd thing is that the Decepticon logo is seen all the time in the Constructicons from the beginning, before being captured by this robot. So, if they weren't Decepticons, how did they have the Decepticon logo? Another hint that they weren't Decepticons is that when they tell Omega Supreme to leave Crystal City, they tell him "The Decepticons are attacking; you are needed", to go to somewhere else to fight and leave Crystal City, but the Constructicons say to him "the Decepticons are attacking" as if they weren't Decepticons. And by the very same time they say this, their Decepticon logo is seen again.

So, were the Constructicons Decepticons before betraying Omega Supreme or not?

Comment: The Transformers G1 cartoon is notorious for its [animation errors](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pPokSA2Q4gc). For example, Soundwave was repeatedly depicted with Autobot (rather than Decepticon) insignia on his chest. So as a rule of thumb, when there's an inconsistency between the animation and the dialogue, you should probably have more faith in the accuracy of the dialogue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Generation 1 cartoon continuity

The Constructicons' backstory is definitely confusing in the original *Transformers* cartoon series.

When they were first introduced in the season 1 episode, "[Heavy Metal War](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Heavy_Metal_War)", they were implied to be new Decepticons, having recently been built by the other Decepticons on Earth.

> MEGATRON: My Constructicons have returned to our temporary base right on schedule. They were worth the time we spent building them in these caverns.
>
> <sub>*The Transformers* - S01E16 - "Heavy Metal War"</sub>

As you noted though, in the season 2 episode, "[The Secret of Omega Supreme](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/The_Secret_of_Omega_Supreme_(episode))", Omega Supreme told Optimus Prime that he was friends with them on Cybertron millions of years earlier, until they betrayed him after being brainwashed by [Robosmasher](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Robosmasher) into joining Megatron's forces.

This episode doesn't specifically say that they were Autobots at the time of their friendship with Omega Supreme, nor does it specifically say that they weren't Decepticons. It just suggests that they weren't malevolent, or loyal to Megatron, prior to being brainwashed by Robosmasher.

This version of events was also mostly a subjective flashback from Omega Supreme's point of view, but certain aspects of his story were corroborated by others. For example, Optimus Prime wasn't familiar with the backstory of the Constructicons, but he did remember Megatron using Robosmasher to reprogram robots to swell the ranks of the Decepticons.

> OMEGA SUPREME: Megatron had built a new machine.
>
> OPTIMUS PRIME: I remember... the Robosmasher. He used it to swell the ranks of the Decepticons. He'd immobilize robots and reprogram them for Megatron's uses.
>
> <sub>*The Transformers* - S02E29 - "The Secret of Omega Supreme"</sub>

And when Omega Supreme confronted the Constructicons in the present day, [Scrapper](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Scrapper_(G1)) called him "old friend", and stated that Robosmasher gave him a mean streak.

> SCRAPPER: Well, old friend. That Robosmasher certainly gave you a mean streak. Too bad it didn't finish the job!
>
> <sub>*The Transformers* - S02E29 - "The Secret of Omega Supreme"</sub>

In the season 3 episode, "[Five Faces of Darkness, Part 4](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Five_Faces_of_Darkness,_Part_4)", there was another flashback detailing the origin of the Transformers as a whole, and one scene depicted as Megatron having been built by the Constructicons, or Transformers that looked very much like them (except that there were eight of them, rather than six, as in the present day).

> [image]
>
> <sub>*The Transformers* - S03E04 - "Five Faces of Darkness, Part 4"</sub>

At this point in Cybertronian history, the Autobots and Decepticons were said to be already at war, which would presumably make these Constructicons (or their look-alikes) Decepticons. And this had to've taken place prior to the events Omega Supreme recounted in "The Secret of Omega Supreme".

Certain visual details, like the Constructions having Decepticon insignia while being friends with Omega Supreme could be put down to [animation errors](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Animation_error), which the series is notorious for. But the varying ways in which the Constructicons were presented in "Heavy Metal War", "The Secret of Omega Supreme", and "Five Faces of Darkness, Part 4" don't flow well together, and tend to suggest that the writers just weren't making much effort to keep continuity straight in this regard.

Unfortunately, this confusing history is never truly resolved within the cartoon itself. The flashback in "Five Faces of Darkness, Part 4" implies that the Constructicons were likely affiliated with the Decepticons in some way prior to being brainwashed by Robosmasher. However, we're given no explanation for why they'd create Megatron, and then later behave as peaceful Transformers who had to be brainwashed into joining his cause.

---

### Japanese Generation 1 cartoon continuity

We get a *little* more info to work with in relation to the [Japanese *Transformers* continuity](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Japanese_Generation_1_cartoon_continuity), thanks to a toy of the Autobot, Hauler, which was released exclusively for the Japanese market in 2003. For context, the Japanese continuity acknowledges the first three seasons of the US cartoon series, and then goes off in its own direction afterwards, so everything shown above is canon in Japan.

A bio included with the toy in question revealed that Hauler -- who made a brief appearance (in vehicle mode only) in the first episode of the US cartoon series -- was originally a Constructicon who joined the Cybertrons after losing his comrades to an assault by Megatron. This seems like it was intended to line up with Omega Supreme's flashback in "The Secret of Omega Supreme".

> Road Hauler was a member of the construction team for the Cybertronian metropolis of Crystal City. After losing his comrades to an assault by Megatron, he joined the Cybertrons. Since awakening on Earth, he has returned to his original purpose of securing energy resources for which he travels the world. A highly capricious self expressionist, he frequently changes his colouration and optional equipment. Road Hauler is equipped with a variety of exploratory devices and a crane arm capable of lifting objects up to 60 tonnes. In robot mode, he wields a Vibro-Force gun and is capable of launching missiles from his wrist sockets. He can also launch his hands and guide them by remote control, allowing him to complete tasks beyond his reach.
>
> [image]
>
> <sub>[Skyquake87's Review: E-Hobby Road Hauler](https://www.tfarchive.com/toys/reviews/reiss_roadhauler.php)</sub>

Note that in the Japanese *Transformers* continuity, the Autobots are known as 'Cybertrons' and the Decepticons as 'Destrons'.

> It is a world transformed. Where things are not quite what they seem. It is the world of the Transformers...a world of heroic Cybertrons and evil Destrons!
>
> [image]
>
> <sub>[E-HOBBY EXCLUSIVE 88 "HAULER"](https://www.tf-1.com/articles/reissue/Hauler_template.html)</sub>

The bio also makes reference to Hauler frequently changing his colouration; likely a nod to the fact that he was coloured orange/yellow duing his brief appearance in the cartoon.

> [image]
>
> <sub>*The Transformers* - S01E01 - "More Than Meets the Eye, Part 1"</sub>

---

### Wings Universe continuity

A pair of bios published within *[Hasbro Transformers Collectors' Club #42](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Hasbro_Transformers_Collectors%27_Club_issue_42)* (December, 2011) attempt to tie together all the references cited above into something resembling a cohesive whole.

The first bio -- for the Autobot, Hauler -- reiterates that he was formerly a Constructicon who joined the Autobots after the other Constructicons started acting suspiciously, following a routine maintenance visit to Crystal City. The bio explicitly mentions the friendship between the Constructicons and Omega Supreme, a clear reference to the flashback shown in "The Secret of Omega Supreme".

> Hauler, or "Load Hauler" as known by some, was a member of the original constructicon team for the magnificent metropolis of Crystal City. It was he who introduced Omega Supreme to Hook, Scrapper, Scavenger, Bonecrusher, Mixmaster, and Longhaul, securing their friendship.
>
> As a member of a Constructicon exploration team, Hauler was among the first sent to a potential build site. It was his duty to assess the resources of any given location, as well as develop usable roads and transport routes for the other Constructicons to follow. It was a task perfectly suited to his personality. Highly detail-oriented yet astoundingly capricious, Hauler often submitted several routes and schematics allowing his back-up plans to have back-up plans.
>
> Hauler became suspicious of the Constructicon cause shortly after Hook and his team disappeared briefly, following a routine maintenance visit to Crystal City. For when they returned, it seemed as though their personalities had been turned upside-down. Not to mention the rumors that they were the ones responsible for the destruction of the city. Hauler soon found himself exploring another possible route: one that led to the Autobots.
>
> Facing his former comrades in battle is an incredible challenge for Hauler, but under the direct command of Optimus Prime, Hauler believes it is a challenge that he will be able to overcome.
>
> [image]
>
> <sub>*Hasbro Transformers Collectors' Club #42*</sub>

The second bio -- for the Constructicon, Devastator -- indicates that there were considerably more than six Constructicons originally, and that they aligned themselves with the Decepticons when the war broke out, prior to being brainwashed by Robosmasher.

> Before the war, the Constructicons had built countless structures across Cybertron, including their greatest feat - The Crystal City. They were hailed for their technical genius and skill. Unafraid to take credit for the achievement, Hook soon rose to command all Constructicons, bringing his five closest advisors with him.
>
> Forced by the rulers of Kaon - keepers of the smelting pools and source of Cybertron's raw construction materials - Hook prudently aligned his faction with the Decepticons. For a small group of dissenters, this was not enough. These seven renegades, in a cavern deep under Cybertron's surface, constructed Megatron as a means of eliminating their enemies and capturing power for themselves.
>
> Megatron, however, did not want to share power and soon Hook and the other ruling Constructicons became a target for Robosmasher. Brainwashed and rebuilt, Hook and his cohorts would lead their army of Constructicons for Megatron's cause. And as Devastator, they would become his battering ram!
>
> [image]
>
> <sub>*Hasbro Transformers Collectors' Club #42*</sub>

From the way it's phrased though (and reading between the lines a little bit), it sounds like the six leading Constructicons were forced to make this decision under pressure from the rulers of [Kaon](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Kaon_(polity)) city, and that they weren't necessarily fully on board with the Decepticons' warmongering agenda. It also suggests that Megatron was built by a group of "renegade" Constructions, rather than the six main Constructicons still shown to be active in stories set in the 20th and 21st centuries.

These implications are presumably made in an attempt to justify why the six main Constructicons were on good terms with Omega Supreme after Megatron's creation, why they had Decepticon insignia at the time, and why Megatron needed to brainwash them to bring them in line. If we take this account to be true, it would seem they were paying lip service to being Decepticons, in the interests of self-preservation, prior to being brainwashed into becoming true believers by Robosmasher.